# What is the difference between `docker-compose run client yarn lint` vs `cd client && yarn lint`

Tags: docker, docker-compose, eslint, eslintrc

Hopefully this can be answered in a generic sense without needing to know about more specifics of my docker setup.

When I run `docker-compose run client yarn lint` the `.eslintrc` file in my `client` directory is not respected, even when explicitly passed with the `--config` option.  When I first `cd client` and then `yarn lint`, the `.eslintrc` works as expected.

I don't understand why these would lead to different results. From my understanding, `docker-compose run client yarn lint` spins up the `client` container and then runs `yarn lint` inside it. Which seems to me like it should be the same thing as running `yarn lint` from the `client` directory.

Anything that can explain why these two processes could be different would be really helpful, even if not explicitly solving my problem!

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I forgot to build my `client` container so I was running `yarn lint` against the old `client` container image with the old `.eslintrc` file.  Whoops!